# Laravel flatten won't flatten array error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In my Laravel project I'm trying to flatten an array to ensure consistency, for some reason, the attached screenshot showing my data format returned from my project won't flatten with the `flatten()` method.

I get an error:

> Error: Call to a member function flatten() on array

Which is quite generic, I've tried using `->toArray()` before flattening but this doesn't give me any data, what am I doing wrong here?

The logic exists within a Laravel job, thus the console log

[image: array]

```php
/**
 * Group data
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function groupData(
  $data,
  $groupBy,
  $groupByFormat,
  $additionFromField = ''
) {
  $results = $data->groupBy(function ($item, $key) use ($groupBy, $groupByFormat) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($item->{$groupBy});
    return $date->format($groupByFormat);
  });

  // grouping by some kind of total
  if (!empty($additionFromField)) {

    $results = $results->map(function ($item, $key) use ($additionFromField) {
      $totals = 0;
      foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $totals += $value->{$additionFromField};
      }
      return [
        'items' => count($item),
        'total' => $totals ?? 0
      ];
    });

    $calcedData = [];
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
      array_push($calcedData, [
        'period_to' => $key,
        'items' => $result['items'],
        'total' => $result['total']
      ]);
    }

    return $calcedData;
  }

  // standard grouping of data
  $results = $results->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item[0];
  });

  return $results;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{

  $filters = json_decode($this->report->discovery_filters, true);
  $data = [];

  foreach ($filters as $findableKey => $findable) {

    /*
    ** If there are datasets on the findable objec, then we assume
    ** that we can build up a chart or some data structure.
    */
    if (isset($findable['datasets'])) {
      $pushableDatasets = [];
      foreach ($findable['datasets'] as $datasetKey => $dataset) {

        // query data
        if (isset($dataset['query'])) {

          $additionFromField = $dataset['query']['additionFromField'] ?? '';

          $res = DB::table($dataset['query']['table'])
                         ->select($dataset['query']['columns'])
                         ->where($dataset['query']['filterBy'])
                         ->orderBy($dataset['query']['orderBy']['field'], $dataset['query']['orderBy']['direction'])
                         ->get()
                         ->chunk(100);

          $res = $res->flatten();

          if (isset($dataset['query']['useGrouping']) && $dataset['query']['useGrouping'] == 'yes') {
            $results = $this->groupData(
              $res,
              $dataset['query']['groupBy'],
              $dataset['query']['groupByFormat'],
              $additionFromField
            );

            var_dump($results); // shown in the screenshot
            $resultData = $results->flatten();

            array_push($pushableDatasets, $this->getStructure($findable, $datasetKey, $resultData));
          }

        }

      }

      $findable['datasets'] = $pushableDatasets;
    }

    array_push($data, $findable);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Call to a member function flatten() on array

The error message is quite accurate and descriptive. [`flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten) is a member function of an object (in this case, the Laravel Collection object) and an array is not an object.

You need to convert the array to a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collection) first, then you can flatten it:

```
$flattened = collect($results)->flatten();
```

Comment: Okay, cool, but now, with that, my returned array no longer has the key/value pairs

Comment: What I've done is updated my original description with a more accurate representation of that functions

Comment: The `flatten` method converts a multi-dimentional array to a single dimension array. What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I need an array of objects, my original description with that image isn't flattened, but flattening it means I loose the keys

Comment: You need to look at your `groupData` method then as that is converting your `$res` eloquent collection from your DB query to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = collect($results)->flatten();
```

In your case you can also use array_flatten() I guess. Here is the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-flatten